# Как вывести данные о ачивках?

Tags: php

Есть таблицы:

```
achievements{
  id - ID достижения
  name - Название достижения
  url - Ссылка на картинку достижения
  descripton - Описание достижения
}
```

и

```
users_achievements{
user_id - ID владельца достижения
achiev_id - ID самого достижения
}
```

Как мне при помощи php вывести все имеющиеся у пользователя "ачивки"?

Заранее большое вам спасибо!

Comment: При помощи условий в `SQL` с разных таблиц выводите.

Comment: Так вот я и не знаю как вывести. Вот и прошу помощи. Если бы знал, то не задавал бы этот вопрос

Comment: Поиск `mysql tutorial` выводит много всего

Comment: @u_mulder, Причем тут mysql tutorial? Мне надо вывести на страницу эти данные. Как сделать запрос, я знаю, но не знаю, как мне сделать так, что бы эти базы друг с другом "сообщались" что ли? Надо что: Есть ID страницы пользователя из GET, далее надо сделать запрос к базе users_achievements, в которой надо вытянуть все строки, где user_id совпадает с $_GET['id'], но когда я пытаюсь это сделать, он выводит мне лишь последнюю запись. И еще надо, что бы из базы achievements выбирались те "ачивки", где ID равняется achiev_id из таблицы users_achievements. Вот как мне сделать все эти запросы?

Comment: Допустим у вас есть `id` нужного пользователя. Делаем запрос в таблицу `users_achievements`, чтобы узнать какие `id` ачивок нам нужны. Ну и потом в цикле выводите все данные о ачивках,которые вы извлекли перед этим в `sql-запросе`

Comment: Вы сами себе как-то противоречите, не замечаете? Как сделать вы знаете, но как сделать спрашиваете.

Comment: @u_mulder, я понимаю, как это должно работать, но как сделать, что бы работало не знаю. Вот в чем проблема :D

Comment: Если вы все-таки почитаете `mysql tutorial` то возможно узнаете что такое `JOIN`. А ответить на вопрос почему у вас выводится лишь последняя запись, не видя вашего кода, сможет лишь телепат.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать объеденный запрос ([JOIN](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/JOIN.html)), чтобы связать две таблицы
Пример запроса будет таким

```
SELECT * FROM users_achievements ua  
    INNER JOIN achievements a ON ua.achiev_id = a.id  
    WHERE ua.user_id = {ID пользователя сюда}
```

Далее выполняете этот sql код
*P.S.
Это пример запроса, возможно не совсем правильный так как ваш вопрос не совсем точный*